# Display differences between two string records in an Access report

Tags: ms-access, vba, diff

I'm looking to modify code within MS Access in order to display differences between 2 records via underline/strikethrough if possible.  This is currently a tedious manual process.  A bit of background...

- Records are called from SQL Server 2008r2
- MS Access 2007 is utilized as a report generator (output - pdf)
- String char length within each record varies between 500 to 10,000
- 1 record compared against another record
- Record A would utilize strikethrough to identify what is not within Record B
- Record B would utilize underlining to identify what is not within Record A
- Multiple instances of comparison throughout document

Excuse my naivety but is this possible?  If so do you have any good answers/reference material that can point me in the right direction?

Comment: First thing you need to do as a newb is to look at the posting rules. StackOverflow is more aimed at helping people with specific problems they're experiencing than linking you to reference material that you can find yourself via Google...  Would suggest you do some googling, then try some things, and post your code here for help

Answer (score 0):

You may find [google-diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) to be a useful starting point. They even provide links to demo pages (like [this one](https://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/svn/trunk/demos/demo_diff.html) for the `diff` operation).

However, what they won't give you is VBA code. You could conceivably port the code from one of the languages they do offer (alas, no VB.NET either), or shell out from VBA to call an external process in one of those languages.

There is also [DiffUtils for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm) which might offer some assistance, depending on your specific needs.